# Some basic questions on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through the rails tutorial at the below link, i have a few questions.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:bundler

What is equivalent command for this in windows, subl is not recognized in windows. What is a `GemFile` and What is a `Gem`?

```
$ cd first_app/
$ subl Gemfile
```

What does bundle mean?

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**subl :**  subl is the command-line command to launch Sublime Text on OS X.

**gem :** is a packaged Ruby application or library(third-party code as you just installed) .

**Gemfile :** It is files allow you to specify what gem dependencies are needed for your Rails application.

**Bundler** manages an application's dependencies.

Refer [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The Gemfile is a list of code your program needs. In Ruby, to be cute, we call these gems. So there are gems to do things like read HTML, and if you wanted to use it, you would put it in your Gemfile.

Saying `subl Gemfile` means that you are opening the Gemfile with the Sublime text editor. You don't need the sublime text editor, you can use any text editor you like. For you probably try nano or pico (`nano Gemfile` and `pico Gemfile`) or if you don't want to edit the files in your terminal, your OS almost certainly has one you can use (on Windows, there is Notepad and on Mac TextEdit). It would be wise to get an editor that can understand and highlight code, though.